# unicode characters conversion in R

Tags: r, unicode

I have this `MTST` column, which when printed yields

```
 [1] "<U+0391>G<U+03A1><U+0399><U+039D><U+0399><U+039F>                                 "
 [2] "<U+0391>G<U+03A7><U+0399><U+0391><U+039B><U+039F>S                                "
 [3] "<U+0391><U+0399>G<U+0399><U+039D><U+0391>                                  "
 [4] "<U+0391><U+0399>G<U+0399><U+039F>                                   "
 [5] "<U+0391><U+0399><U+0394><U+0397><U+03A8><U+039F>S                                 "
 [6] "<U+0391><U+039A><U+03A4><U+0399><U+039F>(<U+03A0><U+03A1><U+0395><U+0392><U+0395><U+0396><U+0391>)                          "
 [7] "<U+0391><U+039B><U+0395><U+039E><U+0391><U+039D><U+0394><U+03A1><U+039F><U+03A5><U+03A0><U+039F><U+039B><U+0397>                          "
 [8] "<U+0391><U+039B><U+0399><U+0391><U+03A1><U+03A4><U+039F>S                                "
```

I tried using `Unicode` library and do `MTST<- as.u_char(MTST)` that gives

```
[1] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

I've also tried `dump` and `dput` but nothing changed.

Note that `MTST` is initially of type `character`.

Appreciate your help. Thanks

**edit:** below `dput(MTST)` is shown

```
c("<U+0391>G<U+03A1><U+0399><U+039D><U+0399><U+039F>                                 ",
"<U+0391>G<U+03A7><U+0399><U+0391><U+039B><U+039F>S                                ",
"<U+0391><U+0399>G<U+0399><U+039D><U+0391>                                  ",
"<U+0391><U+0399>G<U+0399><U+039F>                                   ",
"<U+0391><U+0399><U+0394><U+0397><U+03A8><U+039F>S                                 ",
"<U+0391><U+039A><U+03A4><U+0399><U+039F>(<U+03A0><U+03A1><U+0395><U+0392><U+0395><U+0396><U+0391>)                          ",
"<U+0391><U+039B><U+0395><U+039E><U+0391><U+039D><U+0394><U+03A1><U+039F><U+03A5><U+03A0><U+039F><U+039B><U+0397>                          ",
"<U+0391><U+039B><U+0399><U+0391><U+03A1><U+03A4><U+039F>S                                ",
"<U+0391><U+039D><U+0391><U+0392><U+03A1><U+03A5><U+03A4><U+0391>                                ",
"<U+0391><U+039D><U+0394><U+03A1><U+0391><U+0392><U+0399><U+0394><U+0391>                               ",
"<U+0391><U+039D>OG<U+0395><U+0399><U+0391>                                 ",
"<U+0391><U+03A1><U+0391><U+039E><U+039F>S                                  ",
"<U+0391><U+03A1><U+0391><U+03A7>O<U+0392><U+0391>                                 ",
"<U+0391><U+03A1>G<U+039F>S(<U+03A0><U+03A5><U+03A1>G<U+0395><U+039B><U+0391>)                          ",
"<U+0391><U+03A1>G<U+039F>S<U+03A4><U+039F><U+039B><U+0399>                               ",
"<U+0391><U+03A1><U+03A4><U+0391> (<U+03A0><U+039F><U+039B><U+0397>)                             ",
"<U+0391><U+03A1><U+03A4><U+0391> (F<U+0399><U+039B><U+039F>T<U+0395><U+0397>)                          ",
"<U+0391>S<U+03A4><U+0395><U+03A1><U+039F>S<U+039A><U+039F><U+03A0><U+0395><U+0399><U+039F>                           ",
"<U+0391>S<U+03A4><U+03A1><U+039F>S                                  ",
"<U+0391>S<U+03A4><U+03A5><U+03A0><U+0391><U+039B><U+0391><U+0399><U+0391>                              ",
"<U+0392><U+0391><U+039C><U+039F>S                                   ",
"<U+0392><U+0395><U+039B><U+039F> (<U+039A><U+039F><U+03A1><U+0399><U+039D>T<U+0399><U+0391>S)                        ",
"<U+0392><U+039F><U+039B><U+039F>S                                   ",
"<U+0392><U+03A5><U+03A4><U+0399><U+039D><U+0391>                                  ",
"G<U+039F><U+03A1><U+03A4><U+03A5>S                                  ",
"G<U+03A5>T<U+0395><U+0399><U+039F>                                  ",
"<U+0394><U+0395>SF<U+0399><U+039D><U+0391>                                 ",
"<U+0394><U+0399><U+0391><U+0392><U+039F><U+039B><U+0399><U+03A4>S<U+0399>                              ",
"<U+0394><U+039F><U+039C><U+039F><U+039A><U+039F>S                                 ",
"<U+0394><U+03A1><U+0391><U+039C><U+0391>                                   ",
"<U+0395><U+0394><U+0395>SS<U+0391>                                  ",
"<U+0395><U+039B><U+0395><U+03A5>S<U+0399><U+039D><U+0391>                                ",
"<U+0395><U+039B><U+039B><U+0397><U+039D><U+0399><U+039A><U+039F> ae<U+03C1>                            ",
"<U+0396><U+0391><U+039A><U+03A5><U+039D>T<U+039F>S                                ",
"<U+0396><U+0391><U+039A><U+03A5><U+039D>T<U+039F>S_<U+03A0><U+039F><U+039B><U+0397>                           ",
"<U+0396><U+0391><U+03A1><U+039F>S                                   ",
"<U+0397><U+03A1><U+0391><U+039A><U+039B><U+0395><U+0399><U+039F>                                ",
"T<U+0391>S<U+039F>S                                   ", "T<U+0397><U+03A1><U+0391> (S<U+0391><U+039D><U+03A4><U+039F><U+03A1><U+0399><U+039D><U+0397>",
"<U+0399><U+0395><U+03A1><U+0391><U+03A0><U+0395><U+03A4><U+03A1><U+0391>                               ",
"<U+0399><U+039A><U+0391><U+03A1><U+0399><U+0391>_<U+0391>/<U+0394>                              ",
"<U+0399>O<U+0391><U+039D><U+039D><U+0399><U+039D><U+0391>                                ",
"<U+039A><U+0391><U+0392><U+0391><U+039B><U+0391> (<U+03A0><U+039F><U+039B><U+0397>)                           ",
"<U+039A><U+0391><U+0392><U+0391><U+039B><U+0391>(<U+0391><U+039C><U+03A5>G<U+0394><U+0391><U+039B><U+0395>O<U+039D><U+0391>S)                    ",
"<U+039A><U+0391><U+039B><U+0391><U+0392><U+03A1><U+03A5><U+03A4><U+0391>                               ",
"<U+039A><U+0391><U+039B><U+0391><U+039C><U+0391><U+03A4><U+0391>                                ",
"<U+039A><U+0391><U+039B><U+0391><U+039C><U+03A0><U+0391><U+039A><U+0391>                               ",
"<U+039A><U+0391><U+03A1><U+0394><U+0399><U+03A4>S<U+0391>                                ",
"<U+039A><U+0391><U+03A1><U+03A0><U+0391>T<U+039F>S_<U+0391>/<U+0394>                            ",
"<U+039A><U+0391><U+03A1><U+03A0><U+0391>T<U+039F>S_<U+03A0><U+039F><U+039B><U+0397>                           ",
"<U+039A><U+0391><U+03A1><U+03A0><U+0395><U+039D><U+0397>S<U+0399>                               ",
"<U+039A><U+0391><U+03A1><U+03A5>S<U+03A4><U+039F>S                                ",
"<U+039A><U+0391>S<U+039F>S                                   ",
"<U+039A><U+0391>S<U+03A4><U+0395><U+039B><U+039B><U+0399>                                ",
"<U+039A><U+0391>S<U+03A4><U+039F><U+03A1><U+0399><U+0391>                                ",
"<U+039A><U+0395><U+03A1><U+039A><U+03A5><U+03A1><U+0391>                                 ",
"<U+039A><U+039F><U+0396><U+0391><U+039D><U+0397>                                  ",
"<U+039A><U+039F><U+039C><U+039F><U+03A4><U+0397><U+039D><U+0397>                                ",
"<U+039A><U+039F><U+039D><U+0399><U+03A4>S<U+0391>                                 ",
"<U+039A><U+039F><U+03A1><U+0399><U+039D>T<U+039F>S                                ",
"<U+039A><U+03A5>T<U+0397><U+03A1><U+0391>_<U+0391>/<U+0394>                              ",
"<U+039A><U+03A5><U+039C><U+0397>                                    ",
"<U+039A>OS                                     ", "<U+039A>OS_<U+03A0><U+039F><U+039B><U+0397>                                ",
"<U+039B><U+0391><U+039C><U+0399><U+0391>                                   ",
"<U+039B><U+0391><U+03A1><U+0399>S<U+0391>                                  ",
"<U+039B><U+0395><U+03A1><U+039F>S                                   ",
"<U+039B><U+0395><U+03A5><U+039A><U+0391><U+0394><U+0391> (<U+039D><U+0397>S<U+0399>)                          ",
"<U+039B><U+0395>O<U+039D><U+0399><U+0394><U+0399><U+039F>                                ",
"<U+039B><U+0397><U+039C><U+039D><U+039F>S                                  ",
"<U+039B><U+0399><U+0394>O<U+03A1><U+0399><U+039A><U+0399>                                ",
"<U+039C><U+0391><U+039A><U+0395><U+0394><U+039F><U+039D><U+0399><U+0391>                               ",
"<U+039C><U+0391><U+03A1><U+0391>TO<U+039D><U+0391>S                               ",
"<U+039C><U+0395>TO<U+039D><U+0397>                                  ",
"<U+039C><U+0395>S<U+039F><U+039B><U+039F>GG<U+0399>                               ",
"<U+039C><U+0397><U+039B><U+039F>S_<U+0391><U+039C>S                               ",
"<U+039C><U+03A5><U+039A><U+039F><U+039D><U+039F>S                                 ",
"<U+039C><U+03A5><U+03A4><U+0399><U+039B><U+0397><U+039D><U+0397>                                ",
"<U+039D><U+0391><U+039E><U+039F>S                                   ",
"<U+039D><U+0391><U+03A5><U+03A0><U+0391><U+039A><U+03A4><U+039F>S                               ",
"<U+039D><U+0391><U+03A5><U+03A0><U+039B><U+0399><U+039F>                                 ",
"<U+039D><U+0395><U+0391> F<U+0399><U+039B><U+0391><U+0394><U+0395><U+039B>F<U+0395><U+0399><U+0391>                         ",
"<U+039E><U+0391><U+039D>T<U+0397>                                   ",
"<U+039F><U+03A1><U+0395>S<U+03A4><U+0399><U+0391><U+0394><U+0391>                               ",
"<U+03A0><U+0391><U+0399><U+0391><U+039D><U+0399><U+0391>                                 ",
"<U+03A0><U+0391><U+039B><U+0391><U+0399><U+039F><U+03A7>O<U+03A1><U+0391>                              ",
"<U+03A0><U+0391><U+03A1><U+039F>S_<U+0391>/<U+0394>                               ",
"<U+03A0><U+0391><U+03A4><U+03A1><U+0391>                                   ",
"<U+03A0><U+0395><U+0399><U+03A1><U+0391><U+0399><U+0391>S                                ",
"<U+03A0><U+039F><U+039B><U+03A5>G<U+03A5><U+03A1><U+039F>S                               ",
"<U+03A0><U+039F><U+03A4><U+0399><U+0394><U+0391><U+0399><U+0391>                                ",
"<U+03A0><U+03A4><U+039F><U+039B><U+0395><U+039C><U+0391><U+0399><U+0394><U+0391>                              ",
"<U+03A0><U+03A5><U+03A1>G<U+039F>S                                  ",
"<U+03A1><U+0391>F<U+0397><U+039D><U+0391>                                  ",
"<U+03A1><U+0395>T<U+03A5><U+039C><U+039D><U+039F>                                 ",
"<U+03A1><U+039F><U+0394><U+039F>S                                   ",
"S<U+0391><U+039C><U+039F>S                                   ",
"S<U+0395><U+0394><U+0395>S                                   ",
"S<U+0395><U+03A1><U+03A1><U+0395>S                                  ",
"S<U+0397><U+03A4><U+0395><U+0399><U+0391>                                  ",
"S<U+039A><U+0399><U+0391>T<U+039F>S                                 ",
"S<U+039A><U+039F><U+03A4><U+0399><U+039D><U+0391>                                 ",
"S<U+039A><U+03A5><U+03A1><U+039F>S                                  ",
"S<U+039F><U+03A5><U+0394><U+0391>                                   ",
"S<U+039F><U+03A5>F<U+039B><U+0399>                                  ",
"S<U+03A0><U+0391><U+03A1><U+03A4><U+0397>                                  ",
"S<U+03A0><U+0391><U+03A4><U+0391>(<U+0392><U+0395><U+039D><U+0399><U+0396><U+0395><U+039B><U+039F>S)                        ",
"S<U+03A0><U+0395><U+03A4>S<U+0395>S                                 ",
"S<U+03A4><U+0395>F<U+0391><U+039D><U+0399> (<U+039A><U+039F><U+03A1><U+0399><U+039D>T<U+0399><U+0391>S)                     ",
"S<U+03A5><U+039A><U+03A5>O<U+039D><U+0391>                                 ",
"S<U+03A5><U+03A1><U+039F>S_<U+0391>/<U+0394>                               ",
"<U+03A4><U+0391><U+039D><U+0391>G<U+03A1><U+0391>                                 ",
"<U+03A4><U+0391><U+03A4><U+039F><U+0399> (<U+0394><U+0395><U+039A><U+0395><U+039B><U+0395><U+0399><U+0391>)                        ",
"<U+03A4><U+0396><U+0395><U+03A1><U+039C><U+0399><U+0391><U+0394><U+0395>S                              ",
"<U+03A4><U+03A1><U+0399><U+039A><U+0391><U+039B><U+0391> <U+0397><U+039C><U+0391>T<U+0395><U+0399><U+0391>S                        ",
"<U+03A4><U+03A1><U+0399><U+039A><U+0391><U+039B><U+0391> T<U+0395>SS<U+0391><U+039B><U+0399><U+0391>S                       ",
"<U+03A4><U+03A1><U+0399><U+03A0><U+039F><U+039B><U+0397>                                 ",
"<U+03A4><U+03A5><U+039C><U+03A0><U+0391><U+039A><U+0399>                                 ",
"<U+03A4><U+03A5><U+03A1><U+0399><U+039D>T<U+0391>                                 ",
"F<U+0391><U+03A1>S<U+0391><U+039B><U+0391>                                 ",
"F<U+039B>O<U+03A1><U+0399><U+039D><U+0391>                                 ",
"F<U+039F><U+03A5><U+03A1><U+039D><U+0397>                                  ",
"F<U+03A5><U+03A7><U+03A4><U+0399><U+0391>                                  ",
"<U+03A7><U+0391><U+039B><U+039A><U+0399><U+0394><U+0391>                                 ",
"<U+03A7><U+0391><U+039D><U+0399><U+0391>                                   ",
"<U+03A7><U+0399><U+039F>S                                    ",
"<U+03A7><U+03A1><U+03A5>S<U+039F><U+03A5><U+03A0><U+039F><U+039B><U+0397>_<U+039A><U+0391><U+0392><U+0391><U+039B><U+0391>                       ",
"O<U+03A1><U+0395><U+039F><U+0399>                                   "
)
```

Comment: @Spacedman quote or not, problem remains the same. any ideas?

Comment: Thoughts: basically you've got a mess. Some chars coded with the Unicode hex notation and some not. Is there anyway you can get a true UTF-8 unicode string from whatever created this monstrosity?

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon I am terribly sorry about that. I will find and re-post

Comment: @KapelNick since you fixed it these comments are redundant and I will delete mine... You can save yourself a lot of bother by copy/pasting the output of the command `dput( MTST )` into your question. This gives us the structure of your object, *exactly as it appears in your R session*.

Answer (score 7):

What you have there looks like plain 7-bit ASCII characters with some attempt at encoding Unicode code-points by wrapping some of them thus: `<U+abcd>`.

This is not a recognised encoding for Unicode, as far as I can tell, partly because how would you put a real `<` in your text? I suppose every `<` could be `<U+jklm>` where `jklm` is the code for an angle bracket... But ick.

So, first, try and get a UTF-8 encoded string from whatever generated this ascii-encoded mess!

However... after some serious hair pulling...

`stringi` to the rescue! Where 'MTST' is your vector of stuff, first convert the angle bracket notation to backslash-u and then use `stri_unescape_unicode`:

```
> require(stringi)
> greek2=gsub(">","", gsub("<U\\+","\\\\u",MTST))
> stri_unescape_unicode(greek2)
[1] "ΑGΡΙΝΙΟ                                 "
[2] "ΑGΧΙΑΛΟS                                "
[3] "ΑΙGΙΝΑ                                  "
[4] "ΑΙGΙΟ                                   "
[5] "ΑΙΔΗΨΟS                                 "
[6] "ΑΚΤΙΟ(ΠΡΕΒΕΖΑ)                          "
```

all the way up to

```
[123] "FΥΧΤΙΑ                                  "
[124] "ΧΑΛΚΙΔΑ                                 "
[125] "ΧΑΝΙΑ                                   "
[126] "ΧΙΟS                                    "
[127] "ΧΡΥSΟΥΠΟΛΗ_ΚΑΒΑΛΑ                       "
[128] "OΡΕΟΙ                                   "
```

once I fixed the bizarrely missing comma and quote mark in your "dput" data (edited your question for you).

Comment: I reckon you did your best given the info i provided. How silly of me, not to provide the whole thing, which i actually did right now, so things have changed a bit. Maybe strip could be of use?

Comment: There's still a missing ", in your pasted data. I fixed that. My code works. Unless you were expecting anything other than Greek. Who knows?

Answer (score 2):

I've written a convenient, general, and internally slightly wonky function in base R that works well for this purpose. Here it is:

```
dsub <- function(input,re,f=function(s,d) paste0(s,c(if (length(d)==0L) NULL else paste0('<',d,'>'),''),collapse='')) {
    splits <- strsplit(input,re,perl=T);
    delims <- lapply(strsplit(gsub(paste0('(',re,')'),'.\\1',input,perl=T),paste0('\\.(?=',re,')'),perl=T),function(x) sub(paste0('^(',re,').*'),'\\1',x[-1],perl=T))
    lapply(1:length(splits), function(i) { s <- splits[[i]]; d <- delims[[i]]; f(c(s,if (length(s)==length(d)) '' else NULL),d); } );
};
```

The idea behind the function is to provide a more powerful variation of `strsplit()` which allows you to not just split the input strings into fields, but have a lambda called once for each input string, which takes both the field list (I called it `splits` or `s` in my code) and the delimiters that delimited each field (called it `delims` or `d`).

Importantly, the final field is never delimited, so `s` is always one element longer than `d`. Now, it should be noted that that's not how `strsplit()` normally behaves; it actually doesn't return a final empty string field if the final delimiter in the input string comprised the end of said string, but I've sort of "patched" that behavior in my `dsub()` function for the sake of consistency; for every call to the lambda `f()`, it is guaranteed that `s` will be one element longer than `d`.

A second quirk is related to the way I extracted the delimiters; that was easier said than done. I used `strsplit()` again, but made the regex a zero-width lookahead assertion to preserve the delimiter content, and then, after the split, I called `sub()` to strip off everything after the delimiter. Now, `strsplit()` behaves weirdly when you use an entirely zero-width regex that matches multiple characters; I think what happens is that it matches the regex twice in the same spot, and then splits up the first and subsequent characters across adjacent returned fields. To solve that I added a dummy char before every instance of the delimiter and then matched that char (non-zero-width, just prior to the lookahead assertion) as part of the split regex, which naturally strips it off.

Anyway, here's a simple demo that shows how you can use `dsub()` with the lambda calling `intToUtf8()` to do this kind of "Unicode interpolation":

```
input <- c('Luc TR<U+00c9>HAN','aa<U+00ca>bb<U+00cb>cc','<U+00CC><U+00Cd>','','  ');
re <- '<U\\+([0-9a-fA-F]{4})>';
f <- function(s,d) paste0(s,c(if (length(d)==0L) NULL else intToUtf8(paste0('0x',sub(re,'\\1',d)),multiple=T),''),collapse='');
do.call(c,dsub(input,re,f));
## [1] "Luc TRÉHAN" "aaÊbbËcc"   "ÌÍ"         ""           "  "
```

And using the rather extensive example data given in this question:

```
input <- c("<U+0391>G<U+03A1><U+0399><..."); ## (excerpted)
do.call(c,dsub(input,re,f));
##   [1] "ΑGΡΙΝΙΟ                                 " "ΑGΧΙΑΛΟS                                " "ΑΙGΙΝΑ                                  " "ΑΙGΙΟ                                   "
##   [5] "ΑΙΔΗΨΟS                                 " "ΑΚΤΙΟ(ΠΡΕΒΕΖΑ)                          " "ΑΛΕΞΑΝΔΡΟΥΠΟΛΗ                          " "ΑΛΙΑΡΤΟS                                "
##   [9] "ΑΝΑΒΡΥΤΑ                                " "ΑΝΔΡΑΒΙΔΑ                               " "ΑΝOGΕΙΑ                                 " "ΑΡΑΞΟS                                  "
##  [13] "ΑΡΑΧOΒΑ                                 " "ΑΡGΟS(ΠΥΡGΕΛΑ)                          " "ΑΡGΟSΤΟΛΙ                               " "ΑΡΤΑ (ΠΟΛΗ)                             "
##  [17] "ΑΡΤΑ (FΙΛΟTΕΗ)                          " "ΑSΤΕΡΟSΚΟΠΕΙΟ                           " "ΑSΤΡΟS                                  " "ΑSΤΥΠΑΛΑΙΑ                              "
##  [21] "ΒΑΜΟS                                   " "ΒΕΛΟ (ΚΟΡΙΝTΙΑS)                        " "ΒΟΛΟS                                   " "ΒΥΤΙΝΑ                                  "
##  [25] "GΟΡΤΥS                                  " "GΥTΕΙΟ                                  " "ΔΕSFΙΝΑ                                 " "ΔΙΑΒΟΛΙΤSΙ                              "
##  [29] "ΔΟΜΟΚΟS                                 " "ΔΡΑΜΑ                                   " "ΕΔΕSSΑ                                  " "ΕΛΕΥSΙΝΑ                                "
##  [33] "ΕΛΛΗΝΙΚΟ aeρ                            " "ΖΑΚΥΝTΟS                                " "ΖΑΚΥΝTΟS_ΠΟΛΗ                           " "ΖΑΡΟS                                   "
##  [37] "ΗΡΑΚΛΕΙΟ                                " "TΑSΟS                                   " "TΗΡΑ (SΑΝΤΟΡΙΝΗ"                          "ΙΕΡΑΠΕΤΡΑ                               "
##  [41] "ΙΚΑΡΙΑ_Α/Δ                              " "ΙOΑΝΝΙΝΑ                                " "ΚΑΒΑΛΑ (ΠΟΛΗ)                           " "ΚΑΒΑΛΑ(ΑΜΥGΔΑΛΕOΝΑS)                    "
##  [45] "ΚΑΛΑΒΡΥΤΑ                               " "ΚΑΛΑΜΑΤΑ                                " "ΚΑΛΑΜΠΑΚΑ                               " "ΚΑΡΔΙΤSΑ                                "
##  [49] "ΚΑΡΠΑTΟS_Α/Δ                            " "ΚΑΡΠΑTΟS_ΠΟΛΗ                           " "ΚΑΡΠΕΝΗSΙ                               " "ΚΑΡΥSΤΟS                                "
##  [53] "ΚΑSΟS                                   " "ΚΑSΤΕΛΛΙ                                " "ΚΑSΤΟΡΙΑ                                " "ΚΕΡΚΥΡΑ                                 "
##  [57] "ΚΟΖΑΝΗ                                  " "ΚΟΜΟΤΗΝΗ                                " "ΚΟΝΙΤSΑ                                 " "ΚΟΡΙΝTΟS                                "
##  [61] "ΚΥTΗΡΑ_Α/Δ                              " "ΚΥΜΗ                                    " "ΚOS                                     " "ΚOS_ΠΟΛΗ                                "
##  [65] "ΛΑΜΙΑ                                   " "ΛΑΡΙSΑ                                  " "ΛΕΡΟS                                   " "ΛΕΥΚΑΔΑ (ΝΗSΙ)                          "
##  [69] "ΛΕOΝΙΔΙΟ                                " "ΛΗΜΝΟS                                  " "ΛΙΔOΡΙΚΙ                                " "ΜΑΚΕΔΟΝΙΑ                               "
##  [73] "ΜΑΡΑTOΝΑS                               " "ΜΕTOΝΗ                                  " "ΜΕSΟΛΟGGΙ                               " "ΜΗΛΟS_ΑΜS                               "
##  [77] "ΜΥΚΟΝΟS                                 " "ΜΥΤΙΛΗΝΗ                                " "ΝΑΞΟS                                   " "ΝΑΥΠΑΚΤΟS                               "
##  [81] "ΝΑΥΠΛΙΟ                                 " "ΝΕΑ FΙΛΑΔΕΛFΕΙΑ                         " "ΞΑΝTΗ                                   " "ΟΡΕSΤΙΑΔΑ                               "
##  [85] "ΠΑΙΑΝΙΑ                                 " "ΠΑΛΑΙΟΧOΡΑ                              " "ΠΑΡΟS_Α/Δ                               " "ΠΑΤΡΑ                                   "
##  [89] "ΠΕΙΡΑΙΑS                                " "ΠΟΛΥGΥΡΟS                               " "ΠΟΤΙΔΑΙΑ                                " "ΠΤΟΛΕΜΑΙΔΑ                              "
##  [93] "ΠΥΡGΟS                                  " "ΡΑFΗΝΑ                                  " "ΡΕTΥΜΝΟ                                 " "ΡΟΔΟS                                   "
##  [97] "SΑΜΟS                                   " "SΕΔΕS                                   " "SΕΡΡΕS                                  " "SΗΤΕΙΑ                                  "
## [101] "SΚΙΑTΟS                                 " "SΚΟΤΙΝΑ                                 " "SΚΥΡΟS                                  " "SΟΥΔΑ                                   "
## [105] "SΟΥFΛΙ                                  " "SΠΑΡΤΗ                                  " "SΠΑΤΑ(ΒΕΝΙΖΕΛΟS)                        " "SΠΕΤSΕS                                 "
## [109] "SΤΕFΑΝΙ (ΚΟΡΙΝTΙΑS)                     " "SΥΚΥOΝΑ                                 " "SΥΡΟS_Α/Δ                               " "ΤΑΝΑGΡΑ                                 "
## [113] "ΤΑΤΟΙ (ΔΕΚΕΛΕΙΑ)                        " "ΤΖΕΡΜΙΑΔΕS                              " "ΤΡΙΚΑΛΑ ΗΜΑTΕΙΑS                        " "ΤΡΙΚΑΛΑ TΕSSΑΛΙΑS                       "
## [117] "ΤΡΙΠΟΛΗ                                 " "ΤΥΜΠΑΚΙ                                 " "ΤΥΡΙΝTΑ                                 " "FΑΡSΑΛΑ                                 "
## [121] "FΛOΡΙΝΑ                                 " "FΟΥΡΝΗ                                  " "FΥΧΤΙΑ                                  " "ΧΑΛΚΙΔΑ                                 "
## [125] "ΧΑΝΙΑ                                   " "ΧΙΟS                                    " "ΧΡΥSΟΥΠΟΛΗ_ΚΑΒΑΛΑ                       " "OΡΕΟΙ                                   "
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another alternative for recovering the true uncode character encoded in a string (borrowed from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248457/gsub-in-r-with-unicode-replacement-give-different-results-under-windows-compared/28249364#28249364)). Here we carefully match the form `<U+[hex]>` and unroll that hex value into a properly sized unicode character with some bit manipulation.

```
trueunicode <- function(x) {
    packuni<-Vectorize(function(cp) {
        bv <- intToBits(cp)
        maxbit <- tail(which(bv!=as.raw(0)),1)
        if(maxbit < 8) {
            rawToChar(as.raw(codepoint))
        } else if (maxbit < 12) {
            rawToChar(rev(packBits(c(bv[1:6], as.raw(c(0,1)), bv[7:11], as.raw(c(0,1,1))), "raw")))
        } else if (maxbit < 17){
            rawToChar(rev(packBits(c(bv[1:6], as.raw(c(0,1)), bv[7:12], as.raw(c(0,1)), bv[13:16], as.raw(c(0,1,1,1))), "raw")))    
        } else {
           stop("too many bits")
        }
    })
    m <- gregexpr("<U\\+[0-9a-fA-F]{4}>", x)
    codes <- regmatches(x,m)
    chars <- lapply(codes, function(x) {
        codepoints <- strtoi(paste0("0x", substring(x,4,7)))
        packuni(codepoints)

    })
    regmatches(x,m) <- chars
    Encoding(x)<-"UTF-8"
    x
}
```

using the sample

```
input <- c("<U+0391>G<U+03A1><U+0399><U+039D><U+0399><U+039F>", "<U+0391>G<U+03A7><U+0399><U+0391><U+039B><U+039F>S","<U+0391><U+0399>G<U+0399><U+039D><U+0391>", "<U+0391><U+0399>G<U+0399><U+039F>", "<U+0391><U+0399><U+0394><U+0397><U+03A8><U+039F>S","<U+0391><U+039A><U+03A4><U+0399><U+039F>(<U+03A0><U+03A1><U+0395><U+0392><U+0395><U+0396><U+0391>)")
```

you get

```
trueunicode(input)
# [1] "ΑGΡΙΝΙΟ"        "ΑGΧΙΑΛΟS"       "ΑΙGΙΝΑ"         "ΑΙGΙΟ"         
# [5] "ΑΙΔΗΨΟS"        "ΑΚΤΙΟ(ΠΡΕΒΕΖΑ)"
```