# converting Unicode characters from string column in R

Tags: r, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

Imported a bunch of CSV and one of the columns has what i think are Unicode chars.

something like:

```
PEÃ<U+0083>â<U+0080><U+0098>A
SOPEÃ<U+0083>â<U+0080><U+0098>A
```

Not in all rows, just some, but I've tried to convert to "human readable" chars but to no avail.

Tested this solution from SO but no success so far: [unicode characters conversion in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807085/unicode-characters-conversion-in-r)

and this brute substitution didn't worked

```
 gsub('Ã<U+0083>â<U+0080><U+0098>', 'Ñ', 'PEÃ<U+0083>â<U+0080><U+0098>A')

[1] "Ã<U+0083>â<U+0080><U+0098>"
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the `encoding = "UCS-2LE"` parameter if you are using `read.csv()` to read the files?

Comment: Yes Matt, but no success so far.