# stri_unescape_unicode() fails on some characters

Tags: r, unicode, encoding, character-encoding, stringi

I have a problem with converting unicode characters in R. I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23808731/5550835) approach, but `stri_unescape_unicode` from library `stringi` fails to return correct value in some cases. Let me show an example where the correct value should be word *Tomáš*:

```
library(stringi)
test <- "Tom<U+00E1><U+009A>"
test <- gsub("<U\\+(....)>", "\\\\u\\1", test)
stri_unescape_unicode(test)
[1] "Tomá\u009a"
```

However, if *š* is represented by [U+0161](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0161/index.htm) rather than [U+009A](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/009A/index.htm), everything works as expected:

```
test2 <- "Tom<U+00E1><U+0161>"
test2 <- gsub("<U\\+(....)>", "\\\\u\\1", test2)
stri_unescape_unicode(test2)
[1] "Tomáš"
```

Now, my problem is that I have large `character` vector with numerous elements like `test` and `stri_unescape_unicode` fails on some charactes like `<U+009A>` here. My question is:

- Is there a way to convert `<U+009A>` with `stri_unescape_unicode` or any other method?
- Alternatively, is there a way to automatically replace unicodes in case `stri_unescape_unicode` fails? That is, in my example `"Tom<U+00E1><U+009A>"` should become `"Tom<U+00E1><U+0161>"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `stri_unescape_unicode()` has not failed. The character has been converted, but it is a control character ("single character introducer" U+009A) and is printed using its code. Garbage in, garbage out.

How R prints Unicode strings depends on the type of the console and the locale used. The following example has been run via the `reprex` package using code page 1252 in Windows. Even though the unprintable character is printed using the `<U+>` or `\u` style, the actual Unicode character does exist in the corresponding R string.

```r
library(stringi)
test2 <- c("Tom<U+00E1><U+009A>", "Tom<U+00E1><U+0161>")
test2 <- gsub("<U\\+(....)>", "\\\\u\\1", test2)
unesc2 <- stri_unescape_unicode(test2)
unesc2
#> [1] "Tomá<U+009A>" "Tomáš"
nchar(unesc2)
#> [1] 5 5
cap2 <- capture.output(cat(unesc2, sep = "\n"))
cap2
#> [1] "Tomá<U+009A>" "Tomáš"
nchar(cap2)
#> [1] 12  5
which(nchar(cap2) > nchar(unesc2))
#> [1] 1
es2 <- encodeString(unesc2)
es2
#> [1] "Tomá\\u009a" "Tomáš"
nchar(es2)
#> [1] 10  5
which(nchar(es2) > nchar(unesc2))
#> [1] 1
```

I think `capture.output()` or `encodeString()` combined with `nchar()` can be used as above to detect strings with bad, i.e., unprintable in current locale, characters. Then, if it seems that all cases of U+009A should actually be U+0161, fixing those is a simple job for `gsub()`, e.g., `gsub("\u009a", "\u0161", unesc2)`, and so on.

Comment: Yes, 'manually' replacing these characters is what I ended up doing back then. Thanks for answering!